# Session Logout Handler is buggy

Tags: php, symfony, session-timeout, symfony-2.3

I am trying to implement session logout functionality and I seem to have a buggy implementation. For starters the timeout is not consistent and appears to logout users at various times. Also when the user gets logged out, it does not redirect them to the login URL that i have specified rather it just stays on the screen and the only way user knows they are logged out is when they click on a link.

Please assist as I have tried and many thanks in advance for your suggesstions:

```
<?php

namespace Main\UserBundle\Component\Session\Handler;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

class SessionIdleHandler implements EventSubscriberInterface {

    protected $session;
    protected $securityContext;
    protected $router;
    protected $maxIdleTime;

    public function __construct(SessionInterface $session, SecurityContextInterface $securityContext, RouterInterface $router, $maxIdleTime = 0) {
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->maxIdleTime = $maxIdleTime;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {
        if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST != $event->getRequestType()) {

            return;
        }


        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if (!$request->hasSession()) {
            return;
        }

        $session = $this->session;
        $session->start(); //on every page request the session is restarted
        $session_data = $session->getMetadataBag();

        $lapse = time() - $session_data->getLastUsed();

        if ($lapse > $this->maxIdleTime) {

                $session->invalidate();
                $this->securityContext->setToken(null);
                $this->session->getFlashBag()->set('info', 'You have been logged out due to inactivity.');
                $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('fos_user_security_login')));

        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return array(
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => array('onKernelRequest', 127),
        );
    }

}
```

Also in my services.yml

```
my.user.component.session.handler.session_idle:
        class: Main\UserBundle\Component\Session\Handler\SessionIdleHandler
        arguments: ["@session", "@security.context", "@router", %session_max_idle_time%]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

And in my parameters.yml

```
session_max_idle_time: 3600
```